# Depending on HOST NAME value for PostgreSQL database in my .env file I get different result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, endpoint

I have created a PostgreSQL with a web server DOCKER CONTAINER and my app running with an API to manage all the endpoints.

The link of my git repo is: https://github.com/JulioValderrama/store-front-project.git

But I am facing problems with the connections with the Database, as depending on the Postgres HOST name value in my .env file one of the two servers (one local running in PORT 4000 and the web server running in the docker container in PORT 3000) will work or will fail.

I have tried the next:

Local server running in PORT **4000**

Docker web server running in PORT **3000**

**HOST "127.0.0.1"**

- Going to¨:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Works fine and get response, now when trying to connect it to any of my database API:

```
http://localhost:3000/products
```

- I get the error:

```
"Could not get PRODUCTS. Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432"
```

- Going to:

```
http://localhost:4000
```

Works fine and get response, now when trying to connect it to any of my database API:

```
http://localhost:4000/products
```

It works! I get the list of all my products!!

**HOST "postgres"**

I put "postgres" because I read online that you have to name HOST as the postgres docker image created, which is my case. And it works for the remote server.

- Going to:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Works fine and get response, then when trying to connect it to database API:

```
http://localhost:3000/products
```

- It works!! It gives me the list of my products !!
- Going to:

```
http://localhost:4000
```

Works fine and get response, then when trying to connect it to database API:

```
http://localhost:4000/products
```

It gives me the error:

```
"Could not get PRODUCTS. Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres"
```

So it seems like there is an error when trying to connect to the database due to the server or the HOST name, I have no idea....

Comment: The database host name will in fact be different if you're running the process outside a container (in which case it will be `localhost`) or in a Compose-based setup (when it will be the Compose service name of the other container).  Another possibility is cloud-hosted databases like Amazon's RDS, where the host name will be something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker-compose.yaml you have linked your machine 5432 to containers 5432 port.

If you are using docker container and want to reach postgres, use `postgres` as `POSTGRES_HOST` value.

If you are running application outside the docker environment use `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1`.

Make sure you haven't installed postgres locally

```
brew uninstall postgres
```

Comment: So I can't actually reach postgres from inside (with docker container) and outside (with my local machine server) at the same time with the same POSTGRES_HOST ?

Also, what did you mean with the machine port 5432 to containers 5432 port ? Is there a problem with that?

Thanks !!

Comment: [In this line](https://github.com/JulioValderrama/store-front-project/blob/88f58c3966374db0856e9dc78dc833ba3e9b2fd4/docker-compose.yaml#L10) you have created link between your host and docker network so you can access at the same time. From host (your laptop) use `0.0.0.0:5432` to connect, from docker container use `postgres:5432`

Comment: Ah yes that is what I do, my question was why those two connect differently with the Postgres database and if it was possible to connect both with the same HOST.

You made that point very clear so thank you very much

Comment: You can use same host name for both docker & local machine. Inside docker network when we say `postgres` it knows ip address of postgres containers and resolves it so we can use that. Here container ip might change depending on situation that's why we use nickname here. In your local system you can modify [/etc/hosts](https://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec95.html) file and add alias where postgres = 0.0.0.0, now you should be able to use `postgres` host value for both environments